# How to control http headers in JSF?

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, http-headers, omnifaces

PF 3.5(4.0), Omnifaces 1.6.3, Mojara 2.1.21

Is it possible to control  http headers which will be sent  inside of JSF xhtml page ? I mean something like:

**.xhtml**:

```
<html xmlns:http="a cool name space">

  <h:head>
    <http:headers header="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  </h:head>
  <h:body> .... </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: OmniFaces 1.7 will feature a `CacheControlFilter` for the very purpose. It's already in current snapshots. Javadoc here: http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/javadoc/org/omnifaces/filter/CacheControlFilter.html

Comment: Thank you, interesting and useful feauture of OmniFaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean not to instruct the browser for caching it? Just use a filter and add what you want to your response header:

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(
        req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources //
                                                                        // (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
}
```

**See also:**

- [HTTP response caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413036/http-response-caching)
- [How do a web filter in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979839/how-do-a-web-filter-in-jsf-2)
- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: Thank you, I hope the headers that are set in filter will not be overriden by JSF?

Comment: Actually they aren't. If you watch the network traffic using a tool like firebug (you'll find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374100/how-to-debug-the-http-response-headers-from-a-http-call) insteresting), you'll notice the reponse header has the *Cache-Control* field now.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution by adding the line below to your XHTML page:

```
  <f:event type="preRenderView"
    listener="#{facesContext.externalContext.response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store')}" />
```

Comment: This was a very simple, but effective solution for me.